# Prove $ \int_{0}^{\infty} {x}^{a - 1} \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} a - b x\right) \frac{r}{{x}^{2} + {r}^{2}} d x = \frac{\pi}{2} {r}^{a - 1} {e}^{- br} $

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

I am attempting to calculate the following integral from Whittaker and Watson chapter 6 using the residue theorem. Show that if $a \in \left(0 , 2\right)$, $b > 0$, and $r > 0$, then

\begin{align}
 \int_{0}^{\infty} {x}^{a - 1} \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} a - b x\right) \frac{r}{{x}^{2} + {r}^{2}} d x = \frac{\pi}{2} {r}^{a - 1} {e}^{- b r} \\
\end{align}

During the chapter, we proved that if $Q \left(z\right)$ is a rational function s.t. ${z}^{a} Q \left(z\right) \to 0$ when $z \to 0$ or $z \to \infty$, then

\begin{align}
 \int_{C} {\left(- z\right)}^{a - 1} Q \left(z\right) \mathrm{dz} = 2 \pi i \sum_{\zeta}^{} {\text{Res}}_{z = \zeta} {\left(- z\right)}^{a - 1} Q \left(z\right) \\
\end{align}

and finally that

\begin{align}
 \int_{0}^{\infty} {x}^{a - 1} Q \left(x\right) \mathrm{dx} = \csc \left(a \pi\right) \sum_{\zeta}^{} {\text{Res}}_{z = \zeta} {\left(- z\right)}^{a - 1} Q \left(z\right) \\
\end{align}

**Attempt:** I am not entirely sure how I should proceed with this integral. I assume that I must first show that

\begin{align}Q \left(x\right) = \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} a - b x\right) r}{{x}^{2} + {r}^{2}}\end{align}

will satisfy the necessary asymptotic conditions. I know

\begin{align}
 {z}^{a} Q \left(z\right) & = {z}^{a} \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} a - b z\right) \frac{r}{{z}^{2} + {r}^{2}} \\
 & = {z}^{a} \frac{1}{2 i} \left({e}^{\frac{\pi i}{2} a - i b z} - {e}^{\frac{- \pi i}{2} a + i b z}\right) \frac{r}{{z}^{2} + {r}^{2}} \\
\end{align}

such that when $z = x + i y$ and $| z {|}^{2} > {r}^{2}$

\begin{align}
 | {z}^{a} Q \left(z\right) | \le \frac{| z {|}^{a}}{2} \left({e}^{b y} - {e}^{- b y}\right) \frac{r}{| z {|}^{2} + {r}^{2}} \\
\end{align}

Taking $x = 0$ and allowing $y \to \infty$ causes the above bound to diverge, so I am not sure how to proceed. Am I to use a different theorem for integration. It appeared to me that this integral was specifically designed to be addressed with the above method, for it was the only such problem to feature an ${x}^{a - 1}$ term just like the theorem.

In the meantime, I have computed the residues of the function ${\left(- z\right)}^{a - 1} Q \left(z\right)$.

\begin{align}
 {\text{Res}}_{z = i r} {\left(- z\right)}^{a - 1} Q \left(z\right) & = {\text{Res}}_{z = i r} {\left(- z\right)}^{a - 1} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} a - b z\right) r}{{z}^{2} + {r}^{2}} \\
 & = \lim_{z \to i r} {\left(- z\right)}^{a - 1} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} a - b z\right) r}{\left(z + i r\right) \left(z - i r\right)} \left(z - i r\right) \\
 & = {\left(- i r\right)}^{a - 1} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} a - b i r\right)}{2 i} \\
\end{align}

and likewise

\begin{align}
 {\text{Res}}_{z = - i r} {\left(- z\right)}^{a - 1} Q \left(z\right) & = \lim_{z \to - i r} {\left(- z\right)}^{a - 1} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} a - b z\right) r}{z - i r} \\
 & = - {\left(i r\right)}^{a - 1} \frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} a + b i r\right)}{2 i} \\
\end{align}

When $a$ is even,

\begin{align}
 {\text{Res}}_{z = i r} {\left(- z\right)}^{a - 1} Q \left(z\right) + {\text{Res}}_{z = - i r} {\left(- z\right)}^{a - 1} Q \left(z\right) & = \frac{- {\left(i r\right)}^{a - 1}}{2 i} \left[\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} a - b i r\right) - \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2} a + b i r\right)\right] \\
 & = \frac{- {\left(i r\right)}^{a - 1}}{2 i} \sin \left(- b i r\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} a\right) \\
 & = \frac{{\left(i r\right)}^{a - 1}}{4} \cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2} a\right) \left[{e}^{b r} - {e}^{- b r}\right] \\
\end{align}

I feel that calculating the residue at the origin will be tedious and might not be necessary.

Comment: Hint: integrate $x^{a-1}e^{ibx}/(1+x^2)$ around semicircle in upper half plane. At $x<0$, you have $(-x)^{a-1} = e^{\pi i (a-1)} x^{a-1}$.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan as a similar fact regarding a branch cut was actually leveraged in creating the proof of the chapter. I think you're right that I should just attempt to prove the result directly without overly relying on the theorem established in the chapter. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let contour $C=C_1+C_2+C_3+C_4$, where $C_1$ is the positive real axis, from $\epsilon$ to $\infty$. $C_2$ is large semi-circle on the upper half plane, with radius $R$, $C_3$ is negative real axis, from $-\infty$ to $-\epsilon$. $C_4$ is small semi-circle on the upper half plane, with radius $\epsilon$.

On $C_1$,

$$I_1=\int_0^\infty z^{a-1}\frac{r}{z^2+r^2}e^{ibz}dz$$
On $C_2$, $z=R e^{i\theta}$

$$|I_2|\le \frac{2\pi r}{R^{2-a}}\to0~~\text{as}~~R\to\infty$$

On $C_3$,

$$\begin{align} I_3&=\int_{-\infty}^0 z^{a-1}\frac{r}{z^2+r^2}e^{ibz}dz,~~~z=e^{i\pi}x\\
\\
I_3&=e^{i(a-1)\pi}\int_0^\infty x^{a-1}\frac{r}{x^2+r^2}e^{-ibx}dx\\
\\
I_3&=-e^{ia\pi}\int_0^\infty x^{a-1}\frac{r}{x^2+r^2}e^{-ibx}dx  \end{align}$$

On $C_4$, $z=\epsilon e^{i\theta}$

$$|I_4|\le \frac{\pi}{2r}\epsilon^a\to0~~\text{as}~~\epsilon\to0$$

$$I_1+I_2+I_3+I_4=2\pi i\cdot \text{Res}(z=ir)$$

$$\text{Res}(z=ir)=\lim_{z\to ir} (z-ir)\frac{z^{a-1}r}{z^2+r^2}e^{ibz}=\frac{r^{a-1}e^{-br}}{2i}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}(a-1)}=-\frac{r^{a-1}e^{-br}}{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}a}$$

$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty z^{a-1}\frac{r}{z^2+r^2}\left(e^{ibz}-e^{ia\pi-ib z}\right)dz&=-i\pi \cdot r^{a-1}e^{-br}e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}a}\\
\\
\int_0^\infty z^{a-1}\frac{r}{z^2+r^2}\left(e^{-i\left(\frac{\pi}{2}a-bz\right)}-e^{i\left(\frac{\pi}{2}a-bz\right)}\right)dz&=-i\pi \cdot r^{a-1}e^{-br}\\
\\
-2i\int_0^\infty z^{a-1}\frac{r}{z^2+r^2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}a-bz\right)dz&=-i\pi \cdot r^{a-1}e^{-br}\\
\\
\int_0^\infty z^{a-1}\frac{r}{z^2+r^2}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}a-bz\right)dz&=\frac{\pi}2 \cdot r^{a-1}e^{-br}
\end{align}$$